# add some transition to div with setTimeout method pure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to add some transition when #div getting timeout. I also add webkitTransition in setTimeout method but not found transition. please help me also edit my code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <body>
    <style>
    #div {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
        background:#BD5557;
        position: absolute;
        height: 500px;
        width: 960px;   
    }
</style>
<div id="div">Display out after 1 second</div>

<script>
function displayOut() {
    var x = document.getElementById('div');

    setTimeout(function(){ x.style.display='none';x.style.webkitTransition  = 'opacity 2s ease-in-out';
    x.style.transition = 'opacity 2s ease-in-out';}, 1000);


}
displayOut();
</script>
</body>
</html>





    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to apply `display:none;` at the same time you apply the transition.

Also there is no need to reapply all the css transition properties if they are declared in the css.

```
function displayOut() {
    var x = document.getElementById('div');

    setTimeout(function(){ 
        x.style.opacity='0';
    }, 1000);
}

displayOut();
```

Here is a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/v5ra1zf0/)